# Perturbed linear system, particular form

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a linear system $Ax=b$ where $A$ is real and symmetric, all elements of its main diagonal are strictly positive and all off-diagonal elements are $\leq 0$. Further, $A_{ii} > -A_{ij} \; \forall i,j$ though we do not in general have diagonal dominance. We may assume A is positive definite. All elements of $b$ are in $[0,1)$. We have a unique solution $x$, which has each element $>0$.

Now $A$ is perturbed in the following way:
For some $i,j$, $A_{ij} \leftarrow A_{ij}-\epsilon, A_{ji} \leftarrow A_{ji}-\epsilon,\\ A_{ii} \leftarrow A_{ii} + \epsilon k_i, A_{jj} \leftarrow A_{jj} + \epsilon k_j$, where $\epsilon>0$ is small, and $k_i, k_j$ are known constants in $(0,1)$. The above properties for $A$ are still true.

Can we say anything about the elements of the new solution $x'$ compared to the original solution $x$? For example, is it true that $x' \geq x$ elementwise? By some amount that can be bounded?

The $A$ matrix relates to a graph adjacency matrix. I suspect that if there are cycles involving $(i,j)$ then the change $x'-x$ is larger, and perhaps can be quantified or bound?

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: Is $A$ an M-matrix?

Comment: Hi Frederico, I was not familiar with the term but from reading Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_matrix  yes - sorry, I have added the important point that we may assume A is positive definite, hence is a Stieltjes matrix (and hence an M-matrix). Are relevant results known for such? Thanks for any help.